# Regular expression to match xml tag with the same name

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have 3 xml tag with the same tag name in 1 string :

```
<Name>Case1</Name> <Name>Case2</Name><Name>Case3</Name>
```

I want to extract the content of each node using regular expression. Here is the regexp i have tried so far

```
(<Name>)(.*)(<\/Name>)
```

But it doesn't match as expected. It matches the whole string 
`<Name>Case1</Name> <Name>Case2</Name><Name>Case3</Name>`

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Yes ... the [greedy trap](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap). Consider parsing these values out instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RegExps match greedy (the longest possible sequence) per default. Use ".*?" to specify non-greedy matches:

```
>> set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "<Name>(.*?)</Name>"
>> s = "<Name>Case1</Name> <Name>Case2</Name><Name>Case3</Name>"
>> WScript.Echo r.Execute(s)(0).Submatches(0)
>>
Case1
>>
```

Please consider to use XML tools (XPath, ...) to work with XML data.

Answer (score 2):

I try this Regex.

```
<name>((?:(?!</?name[ >]).)*)</name>
```

**SEE DEMO:**`http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/22`

Answer (score 1):

Dont use RegEx to parse XML/HTML.
Use an XML Parser instead.

I encourage the use of XPath (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

More info why RegEx is no XML Parser can be found here:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression doesn't work as you expect, because you're using a greedy match (`.*`) instead of a non-greedy match (`.*?`).

However, you [shouldn't be using regular expressions for parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171) at all. Use an actual XML parser for extracting data from XML data structures.

```
data = "<root><Name>Case1</Name> <Name>Case2</Name><Name>Case3</Name></root>"

Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.async = False
xml.loadXML data

If xml.parseError Then
  WScript.Echo xml.parseError.reason
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

For Each n In xml.SelectNodes("//Name")
  WScript.Echo n.text
Next
```